# Google Chrome new tab behavior change

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to change the behavior "New Tabs" are opened in google chrome. What I want is whenever I open new tab in chrome the newly opened tab does not start loading itself until I switch to that tab. Is there a extension for a functionality like this? Please inform me.

Comment: Have you asked Mr Google?

Comment: @ne1410s yes, but can't find. Or may be I am not typing the right query.

Comment: This is not worded as a programming question. Try [su], [softwarerecs.se] or reword your question.